# How can I bind multiple keys to a macro?

Tags: emacs

I want to be able to insert:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

#+END_SRC
```

By typing <kbd><</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In org babel you can set structure templates.

Those are added to the variable `org-structure-template-list` in your `.emacs` file as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
         '("s" "#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp\n?\n#+END_SRC"
           "<src lang=\"emacs-lisp\">\n?\n</src>"))
```

Have a look at [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-templates.html)